# Indesign: GREP lookbehind in paragraph style does not search for End of Paragraph

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I'm trying to apply a character style to symbols after End of Paragraph (with some symbols before it) by GREP.

I've tried these combinations:

```
.~b^\K.+
(?<=.~b).+
.\r\K.+
(?<=.\r).+
```

They all work fine when I use them in Searh window, but if I enter them into GREP Style tab of my paragraph style, nothing changes. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I believe this is because paragraph GREP styles only look at one paragraph at a time. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? Maybe using discretionary line break could work

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, Paragraph GREP works with positive lookahead including End of Paragraph, however. I am working on data merge template where appearance of one record depends on content in another record. Thanks for advising to replace End of Paragraph with Line Break, that was exactly what I did to solve the problem, however I just wanted to find out how I could use End of Paragraph in such situation.

Comment: The end of a paragraph is part of said paragraph. If you try to use a GREP style that uses a lookahead to go beyond that (to the next paragraph), you get the same problem.

Comment: The fact is that there's no problem with lookahead to the next paragraph. My GREP applies character style depending the content of the next paragraph. But this does not work with the previous one.